# How to extract headers and Body From Webflux Webclient ExchangetoMono

Tags: spring-webflux

I've been recently study Webflux Webclient

I know exchange has been deprecated , it has be changed into exchangeToMono()

I can't find any information for getting both Headers and body.

Can anyone help me with some sample code!

Thanks!

Expect there will be a sample code or a reference!!!

Answer (score -2):

You can use `exchangeToMono()`, `exchangeToFlux()` methods

Here's an example for Mono:

```java
webClient.get()
        .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
            // here you have access to headers and status, body is not consumed here
            // then you can return Mono<ResponseEntity<Class>>
            return clientResponse.toEntity(String.class);
        })
        .doOnNext(responseEntity -> {
            // do what you want with body, headers, status
        });
```